# Swift UITableView can't calculate content height properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having this weird issue with UITableView that can't calculate it's content's height properly.

I have custom UITableView class that is embedded in another custom UITableView, I want it to auto-adjust it's height to fit content so I have already:

```
override var contentSize: CGSize {
    didSet {
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    return self.contentSize
}
```

And now when I use:

```
self.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension // non-zero value like 40 isn't working either
self.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

the output is the frame that is not full height, when I turn "Scrolling enabled" in this TableView it's scrollable with full content (don't want that):
[image: estimatedRowHeight set to .automaticDimension]

Now when I change

```
self.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

to:

```
self.estimatedRowHeight = 0
```

the output is exactly what I would want to have except the content text is cut...
[image: estimatedRowHeight = 0]

Here's my CommentCell:
[image: CommentCell]

Console isn't showing any errors with autolayout in any case.

Do you maybe know what's going on? I have spent literally days trying to get those comments to work and that's the last thing I need. 
If you need any more info please just tell me.

Edit:
If i change estimatedRowHeight to a large number for example 500 I get loads of empty space under cells:
[image]
So it looks like TableView can't fix the cell height to content. Maybe this will help someone.

Comment: UITableView.automaticDimension will only work properly if top and bottom constraints are set in your custom cell. For example, the bottom constraint of long-text should be set to the 1-hour ago label, and bottom constraint of 1-hour ago label should be set to bottom of the cell.

Comment: I have set it up. Even with the basic label-only it gets messy. Here's output:
https://imgur.com/a/qt6MW56


first photo is
`estimatedRowHeight = 0`


and second is
`self.estimatedRowHeight = 100`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's about the textfield inside the CellView. Did you set it's Layout to wraps?

Also I would try to set it's intrinsic size value to 'placeholder' inside the Size Inspector.

Comment: Intrinsic size value to 'placeholder' is set to 'placeholder' and I have tried 'word wrap' and 'truncate tail'. This is UILabel tho not TextField. Here's output with the most basic cell I could have, text only: 
imgur.com/a/qt6MW56
 first photo is 
`estimatedRowHeight = 0`
and second is 
`self.estimatedRowHeight = 100`

Comment: So I have kinda a breakthrough... I have set a breakpoint inside:
`override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    return self.contentSize
}`
and the first value is 0 (guess before showing up data), later there are 1000 (guess from estimatedRowHeight, 10 cells x 100), and finally there is 1973.333297729492 (and that's the exact height of all cells, i have confirmed this) but it looks like the final value isn't applying to tableView frame. Do you have any ideas?